# How to display php results on same page without showing form

Tags: php, forms

I've tried adding else statements after  and before results.  I'd like the results not to show until after form submitted.   I only want the form to display when the form hasn't not been submitted and the results to show only after the form has been submitted by yourself.
Here's what I have so far...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>

.Spud-Bud-clip {
  font-size: 95%;
  display: flex;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  width: 85%;
  height: 105px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 12px;
  resize: none;

}

.Spud-Bud-button {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
myCapitalizeFunction {
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
<h2>Hyperlink Generator</h2>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $websiteErr = "URL is required";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  }
}  

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>


<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="label_name-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label"><span class="error">* </span>Name</label>
  <div class="col-10">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
  <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="label_name-url-input" class="col-2 col-form-label"><span class="error">* </span>URL:</label>
  <div class="col-10">
<input class="form-control" type="text" class="form-control" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="label_name-text-sumbit" class="col-2 col-form-label"></label>
  <div class="col-10">
<input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>  
</div> 
</div>
<?php
echo "<h5>Now click the button to copy the code.  Next, paste the code.</h5>";
echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>PREVIEW:</strong> <a href="' . $website . '" target="_blank" rel="noopener">' . $name . '</a>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>';
echo '<div class="container-fluid"><div class="input-group add-on"><textarea style="overflow:hidden;" class="form-control clip Spud-Bud-clip"  onclick="this.focus();this.select()"><a href="' . $website . '" target="_blank" rel="noopener">' . $name . '</a></textarea></div>';

?>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.7.1/clipboard.min.js"></script>






<script>
(function($) {
  'use strict'

  $(function() {

    $('.clip').before('<button class="btn btn-outline-primary Spud-Bud-button" data-clipboard-target><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>')
    $('[data-clipboard-target]')
      .tooltip({
        title: 'Copy to clipboard',
        placement: 'right',
      })

    var clipboard = new Clipboard('[data-clipboard-target]', {
      target: function(trigger) {
        return trigger.nextElementSibling
      }
    })

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      e.clearSelection()
      $(e.trigger)
        .attr('data-original-title', 'Copied!')
        .tooltip('show')
        .blur()
        .attr('data-original-title', 'Copy to clipboard')
    })

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
      var modifierKey = /Mac/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? '\u2318' : 'Ctrl-'
      var fallbackMsg = 'Press ' + modifierKey + 'C to copy'

      $(e.trigger)
        .attr('data-original-title', fallbackMsg)
        .tooltip('show')
        .blur()
        .attr('data-original-title', 'Copy to clipboard')
    })

  })

}(jQuery))
</script>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding else statements after  and before results.  I'd like the results not to show until after form submitted.
Here's what I have so far...

I tried to add the below after the body

```
<?php
//If form not submitted, display form.
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])||(($_POST['name']) == "")){
?>
```

Then I added:

```
<?php 
//If form submitted, process input.
} else {
//Retrieve show string from form submission.
```

Just after

```
// define variables and set to empty values
```

Finally added:

```
<?php

} ?>
```

Before /body

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to include what you have so far?

Comment: please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Done.  Sorry about the error on my end.

Comment: Did I include all requirements now?